# COLUMN LENGTH in hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate

Is it possible to retrieve the db column length from hibernate?

```
Property property = (Property)persistentClass.getProperty(propertyName);
                ((Column)property.getColumnIterator().next()).getLength();


                System.out.print(persister.getPropertyColumnNames(propertyName)[0]);
```

This retries the Entity class object length ,not the db column length.

Answer (score 0):

Not from Hibernate directly, but indirectly by using a database vendor specific native query. For Oracle, you can query the table all_tab_columns:

```
SELECT DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH 
FROM all_tab_columns 
where owner = 'SCHEMA_OWNER' 
and TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE'  
and COLUMN_NAME = 'MY_COLUMN';
```

This returns something like this:

```
DATA_TYPE    DATA_LENGTH
------------------------
VARCHAR2     36
```

SQL Server seems to have a similar feature:
http://geekswithblogs.net/AskPaula/archive/2008/07/31/124161.aspx

Comment: Thanks @MirandaVeracruzDeLaHoyaCardina !But I need a way to get the size from hibernate. Do you have any equivalent hql query?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.